# How can I easily upgrade my neo4j database to the newest version

Tags: neo4j, apt, digital-ocean

I'm currently running a neo4j database on DigitalOcean, and used [their help file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-neo4j-on-an-ubuntu-vps) to do so.  In short:

```
wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | apt-key add -
echo 'deb http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list
apt-get update
apt-get install neo4j
```

Now I want to upgrade from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3.  The [neo4j automatic upgrade instructions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/deployment-upgrading.html#_automatic_upgrade) seem to be relevant only once you've downloaded/installed the newest upgrade.

I'm sure there's a simple command or process to upgrade, but I just can't find it.  Can anyone please help?  (I'm **very** much a sysadmin/Unix novice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After running `apt-get install neo4j` I expect that you have 2.1.3 installed. If not try a `apt-get upgrade`.

From 2.1.2 -> 2.1.3 no datastore upgrade is required. When upgrading e.g. from 2.0.x -> 2.1.x the datastore needs to be migrated. This can be enabled by setting

```
 allow_store_upgrade=true
```

in `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.properties`.

So if you apply this setting you should be future proof and get upgrades plus datastore migration (if necessary) upon every `apt-get upgrade`. This setting does not hurt if no store upgrade is necessary.